# C# - Loop executes code on all members of array at once instead of iterating through one at a time

Tags: c#, loops, iteration

I'm making a little boxing game in Unity. I designed a function (attackOverdrive) to accept a whole slew of arguments and then cause the enemy boxer to make attacks based on the data fed into the function. I have another class which sets a bunch of variables and then I read those values, assign them to local variables, and then run my function. Thing is that the code in my loop is executing on all members of the array instead of iterating over them one at a time, resulting in the enemy throwing many attacks at once that were intended to be thrown in sequence. The punchDelayTimer is supposed to count up to a limit, then send a message to instantiate an attack, then loop back and do it again.

I'm going nuts, tried all the different types of iterators and got nowhere. I'm new to C#, no idea what I've done wrong here. The function that sets the variables in the other script is at the bottom of the code block.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class overdrivePiano : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject enemyBoxer;
    private pianoRoll theRoll;
    private string theCoordMod;
    private string[] thePatterns;
    private int howMany;
    private float thePunchDelay, thePatternDelay, theCoordModAmount, punchDelayTimer, patternDelayTimer;
    private Vector2[] theCoords;

    void Start()
    {
        enemyBoxer= GameObject.Find("enemyBoxer");
        theRoll = gameObject.GetComponent<pianoRoll>();
        punchDelayTimer = 0;
    }

    private void readRoll()
    {
        thePatterns = theRoll.patterns;
        thePunchDelay = theRoll.punchDelay;
        thePatternDelay = theRoll.patternDelay;
        theCoords = theRoll.coords;
        theCoordMod = theRoll.coordMod;
        theCoordModAmount = theRoll.modAmount;
    }

    public void onSwitch()
    {
        theRoll.SendMessage("firstVerse");
        readRoll();
        attackOverdrive(thePatterns, thePunchDelay, thePatternDelay, theCoords);
    }

    public void attackOverdrive(string[] patterns, float punchDelay, float patternDelay, Vector2[] coords, string coordMod = "none", float modAmount = 0)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < patterns.Length; i++)
        {
            if (patterns[i] == "triangle")
            {
                int j = 0;
                Vector2[] triangleVectors = new Vector2[] {new Vector2(coords[i].x, coords[i].y + 0.75f), new Vector2(coords[i].x - 0.75f, coords[i].y - 0.75f), new Vector2(coords[i].x + 0.75f, coords[i].y - 0.75f)};
                do
                {
                    if (punchDelayTimer <= punchDelay)
                    {
                        punchDelayTimer += Time.deltaTime; //Debug statement here for i and j both print 0
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        enemyBoxer.SendMessage("createAttack", triangleVectors[j]);
                        punchDelayTimer = 0;  //Debug statement here outputs 9 statements for the value of i: 0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2
                        j += 1; //Debug statement here outputs 9 statements for the value of j: 0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2
                    }
                } while (j < 3);
            }
            else if (patterns[i] == "square")
            {
                
            }
            else if (patterns[i] == "circle")
            {
                
            }
            else if ("verticalLine".CompareTo(patterns[i]) == -1)
            {
               
                var result = Regex.Match(patterns[i], @"\d+$", RegexOptions.RightToLeft);
                if (result.Success) 
                { 
                    //Debug.Log(result.Value);
                } 
            }
        }
    }
}


private void firstVerse()
    {
        patterns = new string[] {"triangle", "triangle", "triangle", "singleRandom", "singleRandom", "verticalLine5"};
        coords = new Vector2[] {new Vector2(-1.3f, 2.5f), new Vector2(0f, -2.5f), new Vector2(1.3f, 2.5f), new Vector2(0,0), new Vector2(0,0), new Vector2(0, 4f)};
        punchDelay = 0.5f;
        patternDelay = 0.5f;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried adding some logging? What values do you see for punchDelayTimer, punhcDelay and Time.deltaTime in each loop?

Comment: punchDelay is set to 0.5 and the timer correctly counts up to it. Once it gets past 0.5 all the code in the else clause executes on all members of the array, rather than just on patterns[i].

Comment: Also any log statement that I put inside the else clause will execute 9 times (3 for each of the 3 triangles) - all timestamped at the same time.

Comment: Where in your loop are you performing your "delay". I.e. how do you wait? The only thing I can see is the value of punchDelayTimer being increased.

Comment: The if clause - punchDelayTimer += Time.deltaTime; - increases the timer as time goes by. Once it gets to the limit set by punchDelay, it's supposed to run the else clause which then resets the punchDelayTimer back to 0 so it can run again. It does all of those things, but 9 times at once instead of one at a time.

Comment: But punchDelayTimer is a number (a float). So increasing just modifies its value. I can't see any code that modifies any timer objects.

Comment: I don't see how that changes anything - if it increments up over time to be compared to another float as a limit, is that not a timer? I can see in logs that it does count up to 0.5 seconds before it runs the code in the else statement, I just don't understand how it's affecting multiple array elements when I'm making reference to patterns[i] - which should be a single element.

Comment: Well there won't be any actual delay. The loop will just run almost instantaneously, so it will look like the enemy is throwing many attacks at once. Add some logging, and log all the different values of i and j. Can you then update your post with these values so we can see the behaviour?

Comment: Okay, logged the values of i and j in the if and else clauses. Thanks for looking at this.

Comment: OK, so the values of i and j look good. It shows that the loop is running sequentially as you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the float timer was the problem. It was iterating through the array properly, but it was all happening on the same frame. I was able to solve the problem by changing attackOverdrive's return type to IEnumerator and then calling it as a coroutine from OnSwitch. I removed the if statement inside the triangle part of the loop and replaced the float timer with Unity's WaitForSeconds class. Here are the functions that changed in case anyone is interested:

```
public void onSwitch()
    {
        theRoll.SendMessage("firstVerse");
        readRoll();
        StartCoroutine(attackOverdrive(thePatterns, thePunchDelay, thePatternDelay, theCoords));
    }

    public IEnumerator attackOverdrive(string[] patterns, float punchDelay, float patternDelay, Vector2[] coords, string coordMod = "none", float modAmount = 0)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < patterns.Length; i++)
        {
            if (patterns[i] == "triangle")
            {
                int j = 0;
                Vector2[] triangleVectors = new Vector2[] {new Vector2(coords[i].x, coords[i].y + 0.5f), new Vector2(coords[i].x - 0.5f, coords[i].y - 0.5f), new Vector2(coords[i].x + 0.5f, coords[i].y - 0.5f)};
                do
                {
                    enemyBoxer.SendMessage("createAttack", triangleVectors[j]);
                    yield return new WaitForSeconds(punchDelay);
                    punchDelayTimer = 0f;
                    j += 1;
                } while (j < 3);
            }
            else if (patterns[i] == "square")
            {
                
            }
            else if (patterns[i] == "circle")
            {
                
            }
            else if ("verticalLine".CompareTo(patterns[i]) == -1)
            {
               
                var result = Regex.Match(patterns[i], @"\d+$", RegexOptions.RightToLeft);
                if (result.Success) 
                { 
                    Debug.Log(result.Value);
                } 
            }
            else if ("single".CompareTo(patterns[i]) == -1)
            {
               
                var result = Regex.Match(patterns[i], @"\d+$", RegexOptions.RightToLeft);
                if (result.Success) 
                { 
                    Debug.Log(result.Value);
                } 
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks to rage_co on the Unity forums, who showed me this fix =]